# Use of hardly...when

Tags: grammar

Pl. see the sentence below

[1]. *Hardly had the bell rung when Matthew started running out of his classroom.*

I guess the construction is correct. If I change this to

[2]. *Hardly the bell had rung when Matthew started running out of his classroom.*

[3]. *When Matthew started running out of his classroom, the bell had hardly rung.*

Is there any grammatical error in these constructions or which one of these is most neat and why. We see the first construction most often.

Thanks---Suddhasattwa, India

Answer (score 0):

Your second sentence is not correct. The reason is that if a sentence is begun with a negative word like **'hardly, scarcely, no sooner** etc. the word order should be reversed *(Negative word + auxiliary + subject + verb*) in that clause.
For more details and examples here is a screen shot of the chapter from the Practical English Usage by Michael Swan:
[image]

Answer (score -2):

Generally you would not start a sentence with "hardly".

This sentence is more correct: "The bell had hardly rung when Matthew started running out of his classroom" although an alternatively would be:
"The bell had hardly started ringing when Matthew started running..."

Your option [3] is valid, but does not flow as well in English as the above suggestion.